# Is it right to pass dependencies into a class that does not use it itself but passes it to some internally used classes

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, constructor

It is this blog that has me really confused:
http://ayende.com/blog/124929/your-ctor-says-that-your-code-is-headache-inducing-explanation

Say I have a class library that provide access control services. I do not want to use any IoC container in the library itself to make it easy to test it (so everything is injected and there are no container.Resolve in library itself). (WCF service and other websites that use this library will use some container to inject dependencies in the constructor.)

Say my core class looks like this:

```
public class UserAccessManagement
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _repo;
    private readonly IHashProvider _hash;
    private readonly ITokenEncryptor _tokenEnc;

    public UserAccessManagement(IUserRepository repo, IHashProvider hash, ITokenEncryptor tokenEnc)
    {
        _repo = repo; _hash = hash; _tokenEnc = tokenEnc;
    }

    public void GrantAccess(string username, string resource)
    {
        User user = repo.FindUser(username);
        new AccessGateKeeper(user.SpnTicket, _hash, _tokenEnc)
            .GrantAccess(resource);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the hash and tokenEnc are not really used by the class but has to be passed to the constructor because internally it has to pass it to gate keeper. The concrete implementation of gate keeper has to be an internal and sealed class for security reasons so it itself cannot be injected in the constructor which would have solved the problem.

So you end up with a lot of dependencies injected through constructor though it does not necessarily mean the class itself is doing too much. The blog says this is horrible. Is there is a better or more proper way to handle this given three requirements:

1. AccessGateKeeper has to be internal and sealed.
2. No IoC in class library for testing reasons.
3. Don't want to use property/method injection as it is less robust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule about not taking a dependency just to pass it on is correct, but from the perspective of your public API, that's not what you're doing either. Since the `AccessGateKeeper` is internal, it's not part of the public API - it's an **implementation detail**. It might as well had been a private helper function of the `UserAccessManagement` class.

Thus, from a public perspective, the `UserAccessManagement` class *doesn't* take a dependency 'just to pass it on'. Instead, you could say that the `UserAccessManagement` class requires the dependencies `IUserRepository`, `IHashProvider` and `ITokenEncryptor` to perform its work.

From a maintainability point, however, the current implementation tightly couples `UserAccessManagement` and `AccessGateKeeper` which may or may not be a problem. However, if it *is* a problem, you could consider wrapping the desired behavior in an interface. A mechanical extraction might look like this:

```
public interface IAccess
{
    void Grant(object ticket, string resource)
}
```

With this interface you could change the implementation of `UserAccessManagement` to:

```
public class UserAccessManagement
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _repo;
    private readonly IAccess _access;

    public UserAccessManagement(IUserRepository repo, IAccess access)
    {
        _repo = repo;
        _access = access;
    }

    public void GrantAccess(string username, string resource)
    {
        User user = repo.FindUser(username);
        _access.Grant(user.SpnTicket, resource);
    }
}
```

An implementation of `IAccess` could look like this:

```
public class Access : IAccess
{
    private readonly IHashProvider _hash;
    private readonly ITokenEncryptor _tokenEnc;

    public Access(IHashProvider _hash, ITokenEncryptor _tokenEnc)
    {
        _hash = hash;
        _tokenEnc = tokenEnc;
    }

    public void Grant(object ticket, string resource)
    {
        new AccessGateKeeper(ticket, _hash, _tokenEnc)
            .GrantAccess(resource);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response! Your explanation makes perfect sense and cleared all my confusion. Your proposed solution is simply awesome. I like this pattern of abstracting out any dependencies that work together into its own class. I can see myself refactoring my codebase based on this. Thank you very much, once again!